# Long series of D3 transitions - code structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

### Synopsis

I am currently working on a project where I use D3 for storytelling. For that purpose, I create a series of d3 graphs and define a transition logic between graphs. Although I am new to js programming, I am very happy with my progress. However, my code is getting very bloated and repetitive. Therefore I am trying to find a better structure for my code going forward.

### Current code structure

For each graph, I define a function that draws that graph from scratch. This function takes a html element as an argument and inserts the graph into the DOM as a child of this element. These functions are used to initialize the graph sequence and for resize events.

I also define the transition logic with another "family" of functions. Those take an existing graph and convert it into another one using d3 transitions.

Lastly, I define functions `getCurrentGraph()` and `setCurrentGraph()` so the resize logic knows which graph to draw. These functions are used inside all other functions. For example, `transitionGraph1Graph2()` calls `setCurrentGraph("graph2")`.

```js
// draw (or redraw) graphs
function drawGraph1(el) {};
function drawGraph2(el) {};
function drawGraph3(el) {};

// transition logic
function transitionGraph1Graph2(el, duration) {};
function transitionGraph2Graph3(el, duration) {};
function transitionGraph2Graph1(el, duration) {};
function transitionGraph3Graph2(el, duration) {};

// get/set a key for the current graph via the DOM
function getCurrentGraph() {};
function setCurrentGraph(graph = "graph1") {};
```

Then I use a closure to make sure that all functions are scoped to a single `.js` file. I only want to expose the transition logic to the global scope.

#### graphsequence.js

```js
graphSequence = function(el = document.getElementById("graphContainer"),
                         duration = 1000) {
  // draw (or redraw) graphs
  function drawGraph1(el) {};
  function drawGraph2(el) {};
  function drawGraph3(el) {};

  // transition logic
  function transitionGraph1Graph2(el = el, duration = duration) {};
  function transitionGraph2Graph3(el = el, duration = duration) {};
  function transitionGraph2Graph1(el = el, duration = duration) {};
  function transitionGraph3Graph2(el = el, duration = duration) {};

  // get/set a key for the current graph via the DOM
  function getCurrentGraph() {};
  function setCurrentGraph(graph = "graph1") {};

  // handle resize events
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    switch (getCurrentGraph()) {
      case "graph1": drawGraph1(el) [break;]
      case "graph2": drawGraph2(el) [break;]
      case "graph3": drawGraph3(el) [break;]      
    }
  });

  // initialize the graph sequence
  drawGraph1(el, duration);

  // expose callbacks for transitioning to the global scope
  return {
    transitionGraph1Graph2: transitionGraph1Graph2,
    transitionGraph2Graph3: transitionGraph2Graph3,
    transitionGraph2Graph1: transitionGraph2Graph1,
    transitionGraph3Graph2: transitionGraph3Graph2
  }
}();
```

#### index.html

```html
<div id = "graphContainer"></div>
<script src="graphsequence.js"></script>
<button onclick="graphSequence.transitionGraph1Graph2()">Transition Graph!</button>
```

### Questions

First, I want to emphasize that my current code works very well and I am not trying to resolve a bug. I am asking for advice on how to structure my code in order to keep the project maintainable in the long run.

- I feel the current implementation is very repetetive. Is there any way to DRY up this workflow 
  and define the logic in a more concise manner?
- The events that trigger the transitions are created with `scrollama.js`. Is there any "scrollytelling" library that has a special integration of D3 that could be used to make the code more structured?
- Is it a good idea to have all this logic in a single `.js` file or should I try to split up the code to make the project more modular?
- Currently, I am working without any javascript framework. I am also not familiar with any frameworks for that language. Does it make sense to start using a framework for a usecase like this? If so, which frameworks are recommended and why?

Comment: *"First, I want to emphasize that my current code works very well and I am not trying to resolve a bug. I am asking for advice on how to structure my code in order to keep the project maintainable"*... so, consider asking your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. However, before doing that, read their help section to make sure your question will be on topic there (SO and Code Review have different rules for a question being on topic).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about the codereview subdomain. My question is in fact about code design and therefore this seems like a good place to ask. I'll  figure out a dummy implementation for my methods and post it there.

Comment: Great. But do not create a dummy implementation: Code Review requires the **real** code. Of course you don not need all of it, just the functions' structure.

Comment: I was thinking about substituting very simple transitions for my animations and sharing everything that builds on top of that. Is there some thread about how detailed a post should be?

Comment: There is [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), but your plan sounds good.